# How to identify a Yubikey (5 NFC) by its HID report descriptor

Tags: uefi, yubikey

I want to access the Yubikeys FIDO2 functionality under UEFI.

The FIDO2 specification says a FIDO2 device can be identified by checking the USB interface (class 3, subclass 0 und protocol 0) and the HID report descriptor (usage page 0xF1D0).

When i connect the yubikey i find it and an interface with the correct class but the usage page in the HID report descriptor is 0x01.

I have one other FIDO2 capable stick from Feitian, this one has the correct interface and the correct usage page.

Do I have to enable FIDO2 on the Yubikey besides enabling the USB FIDO2 interface in the Yubikey manager application?

This is the output of my program for the Feitian stick:

```
Found a possible Fido2 device: 096E:0858
Usb device:
Device:
Vendor: 096E 'FT'
Product: 0858 'FIDO'
SerialNumber: 'unkn.'
DeviceClass: 00
DeviceSubclass: 00
DeviceProtocol: 00
MaxPacketSize0: 40

Interface #00:
AlternateSetting: 00
NumEndpoints: 02
InterfaceClass: 03
InterfaceSubClass: 00
InterfaceProtocol: 00
Interface: 05

Endpoint #0:
EndpointAddress: 84
Attributes: 03
MaxPacketSize: 0040
Interval: 02

Endpoint #1:
EndpointAddress: 04
Attributes: 03
MaxPacketSize: 0040
Interval: 02


HID report s item (01:00) -> Gobal:Usage Page { D0 F1 }
HID report s item (02:00) -> Local:Usage { 01 }
HID report s item (00:0A) -> Main:Collection (Application) { 01 }
HID report s item (02:00) -> Local:Usage { 20 }
HID report s item (01:01) -> Gobal:Logical Minimum { 00 }
HID report s item (01:02) -> Gobal:Logical Maximum { FF 00 }
HID report s item (01:07) -> Gobal:Report Size { 08 }
HID report s item (01:09) -> Gobal:Report Count { 40 }
HID report s item (00:08) -> Main:Input { 02 }
HID report s item (02:00) -> Local:Usage { 21 }
HID report s item (01:01) -> Gobal:Logical Minimum { 00 }
HID report s item (01:02) -> Gobal:Logical Maximum { FF 00 }
HID report s item (01:07) -> Gobal:Report Size { 08 }
HID report s item (01:09) -> Gobal:Report Count { 40 }
HID report s item (00:09) -> Main:Output { 02 }
HID report s item (00:0C) -> Main:End Collection { }
```

And this is the output for the Yubikey:

```
Found a possible Fido2 device: 1050:0407
Usb device:
Device:
Vendor: 1050 'Yubico'
Product: 0407 'YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID'
SerialNumber: 'unkn.'
DeviceClass: 00
DeviceSubclass: 00
DeviceProtocol: 00
MaxPacketSize0: 40

Interface #01:
AlternateSetting: 00
NumEndpoints: 02
InterfaceClass: 03
InterfaceSubClass: 00
InterfaceProtocol: 00
Interface: 00

Endpoint #0:
EndpointAddress: 04
Attributes: 03
MaxPacketSize: 0040
Interval: 02

Endpoint #1:
EndpointAddress: 84
Attributes: 03
MaxPacketSize: 0040
Interval: 02


HID report s item (01:00) -> Gobal:Usage Page { 01 }
HID report s item (02:00) -> Local:Usage { 06 }
HID report s item (00:0A) -> Main:Collection (Application) { 01 }
HID report s item (01:00) -> Gobal:Usage Page { 07 }
HID report s item (02:01) -> Local:Usage Minimum { E0 }
HID report s item (02:02) -> Local:Usage Maximum { E7 }
HID report s item (01:01) -> Gobal:Logical Minimum { 00 }
HID report s item (01:02) -> Gobal:Logical Maximum { 01 }
HID report s item (01:07) -> Gobal:Report Size { 01 }
HID report s item (01:09) -> Gobal:Report Count { 08 }
HID report s item (00:08) -> Main:Input { 02 }
HID report s item (01:09) -> Gobal:Report Count { 01 }
HID report s item (01:07) -> Gobal:Report Size { 08 }
HID report s item (00:08) -> Main:Input { 01 }
HID report s item (01:09) -> Gobal:Report Count { 05 }
HID report s item (01:07) -> Gobal:Report Size { 01 }
HID report s item (01:00) -> Gobal:Usage Page { 08 }
HID report s item (02:01) -> Local:Usage Minimum { 01 }
HID report s item (02:02) -> Local:Usage Maximum { 05 }
HID report s item (00:09) -> Main:Output { 02 }
HID report s item (01:09) -> Gobal:Report Count { 01 }
HID report s item (01:07) -> Gobal:Report Size { 03 }
HID report s item (00:09) -> Main:Output { 01 }
HID report s item (01:09) -> Gobal:Report Count { 06 }
HID report s item (01:07) -> Gobal:Report Size { 08 }
HID report s item (01:01) -> Gobal:Logical Minimum { 00 }
HID report s item (01:02) -> Gobal:Logical Maximum { 65 }
HID report s item (01:00) -> Gobal:Usage Page { 07 }
HID report s item (02:01) -> Local:Usage Minimum { 00 }
HID report s item (02:02) -> Local:Usage Maximum { 65 }
HID report s item (00:08) -> Main:Input { 00 }
HID report s item (02:00) -> Local:Usage { 03 }
HID report s item (01:07) -> Gobal:Report Size { 08 }
HID report s item (01:09) -> Gobal:Report Count { 08 }
HID report s item (00:0B) -> Main:Feature { 02 }
HID report s item (00:0C) -> Main:End Collection { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i sent the request for the HID descriptor to the wrong interface, i sent it to interface 0 but it in my configuration i need to send it to interface 1.

Interface 0 is the keyboard interface and Interface 1 is the FIDO2 interface.